# How to organize side jobs by namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a lot of closely related ActiveJob side jobs and since each needs to run with `perform`, I want to put them together in a folder namespace.

So for example, let's say I have:

```
app/jobs/hello_job.rb
app/jobs/goodbye_job.rb
app/jobs/thank_you_job.rb
```

and I call each of these like `HelloJob.perform_later`.

What I want to have instead is something like:

```
app/jobs/greetings/hello_job.rb
app/jobs/greetings/goodbye_job.rb
app/jobs/greetings/thank_you_job.rb
```

and call them with something like `Greetings::HelloJob.perform_later`.... although this does not work.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out. Having a similar problem.

Answer (score 3):

In **ruby** you can use **modules** as *namespaces*.

So you put the closely related ActiveJobs in a folder and you define each class inside a module with the same name as the folder.

For `app/jobs/greetings/hello_job.rb` this works for me:

```
module Greetings
  class HelloJob < ActiveJob::Base
    queue_as :default

    def perform
      puts 'Hello!'
    end
  end
end
```